# Excel CountIf Condition Query 2 ( initial solution based on SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH)

Tags: excel, count, countif

Can you help me draft the formula for the link? The letters cannot be changed in the sheet. Formula (Row23-28) needs work on the 2nd Tab (NEW).

***Screenshot:***

[image]

[Excel file download link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f34a062152fd6211e93f486bb0ea9f8f20180504075925/58ef95)

@G43beli already helped me out on the first tab,  but im still not able to get the 2nd one. THoughts?

Comment: Can't see your screenshot or your excel file

Comment: links are working fine.. anyone can help me?